# Iterating over specific items of a pair (or tuple) in a list in C++

Tags: c++, c++14, stdlist

Say I have something like:

```
using MyList = std::list<std::pair<string,int>>;
```

How can I get an iterator to just the strings (or ints) of the list? I have a function I'd like to pass *something*.begin() and *something*.end() that is just of the ints. Is there an easy/clever/slick way to do this? Can it be done with a tuple as well?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a standard way to do this but you can write your own iterator adapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is Boost's `transform_iterator`.

```
using MyList = std::list<std::pair<string,int>>;

MyList l{ {"Hello", 42}, {"World", 0} };

auto tr = [](auto const& p){
    return p.first;
};

copy(boost::make_transform_iterator(l.begin(), tr),
     boost::make_transform_iterator(l.end(), tr),
     ostream_iterator<string>(cout, ", "));
```

[live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tq45uHfpz9nNxJt0)

Answer (score 3):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may do something like

```
std::list<std::pair<std::string, int>> pairs = {{"John", 2}, {"Hello", 42}};

auto names = pairs | ranges::view::keys;
auto ints = pairs | ranges::view::values;
auto doubleInts = pairs | ranges::view::transform([](const auto& p){ return 2 * p.second; };
```

Comment: What are `names` and `ints`? Are they lightweight views or full sequences?

Comment: @krzaq: They are lightweight views (as `doubleInts`).